# Is using `lang` attribute in a `style` tag allowed to mark CSS preprocessor language for VueJS? Any drawbacks if we use it?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, stylus

From time to time, I see people write thing like

```
<style lang="scss"> ... </style>

<style lang="stylus"> ... </style>
```

I searched the doc for style tag and `lang` is not part of the validate attribute. Is it recommended to use `lang` like this when writing scoped style that involve additional CSS preprocessor styles?

Comment: Something like would be *necessary* if you're using some additional tool that translates into CSS, and useless otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Vue loader documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html) specifically states to do this. So not only is it recommended, it appears to be required for the feature to work correctly.

It's a [flagrant violation of the HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes) all the same (misusing the `lang` attribute with custom values), but JavaScript frameworks and components aren't exactly known for standards compliance. For one, presumably, no one is actually running their components through a checker. This is probably one of the numerous cases where they don't bother with the `data-` prefix simply because it means unnecessary keystrokes. Which, IMHO, is an incredibly lousy excuse.